# How to convert Go time.Time into MySQL datetime?

Tags: mysql, database, go

I am generating a datetime string in Go and when I insert the generated value into a MySQL table, the value of the column becomes: 0000-00-00 00:00:00 but it is supposed to be: 2019-08-21 11:05:45.

I do not understand why the datetime becomes zero, I guess there is some mismatch.

```
goDateTime := time.Now().Format("02-01-2006 03:04:05")
```

The above code returns datetime as a string. But in my database table the column type is `datetime`. I changed the database type to `varchar` and it worked, but I want to use the `datetime` time.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your date format string is not compatible with MySQL, which requires datetime values to be in `YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss` format, where `hh` is a 24-hour value (see the [manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/datetime.html)). It should be

```
golangDateTime := time.Now().Format("2006-01-02 15:04:05")
```